# jquery :visibility selector usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that somebody wrote and I'm trying to wrap my head around. jquery document says "The :visible selector selects every element that is currently visible." And the code looks something like this:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
   <div class="error-test e-name">Enter Name</div>
   <input name="name" type="text"/>
   <div class="error-test e-email">Enter Email</div>
   <input name="email" type="email"/>
   <div class="error-test e-password">Enter Password</div>
   <input name="password" type="password"/>
   <button class="register" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

And the jquery code looks something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.register', function(d)
    {
     if ($('.error-test').is(":visible") )
       {
        d.preventDefault();
        alert('please fill the form properly before submitting.');
       }
    else
       {
        // do something
       }

And the CSS:
<style>
   .error-test
       {
        display: none
       }
</style>
```

So my question is, can somebody explain what this line is doing: if ($('.error-test').is(":visible") )

And explain why the need to set the css to display: none. I can't wrap my head around the :visible selector.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`if ($('.error-test').is(":visible") )` checks if any error message is currently visible on the screen. If it is then `d.prevenDefault()` stops the submit and an alert is shown. `.error-test` has `display:none` initially so that it is not on screen, some part of js code must be making it visible.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.error-test').is(":visible")` looks for an element with the `class`: `error-test` and wraps it in a jQuery object. After that the method `is` checks whether the object is visible in the DOM or not. if true, the if clause will run.

When in CSS the element's display is set to none it will not appear on page, hence `visible`.

Basically what the whole code does is:
check if there is any error `div` visible, if true abort and alert, if false go on with posting the form.